# Can we change the default time zone for TFS 2018 Email Alerts

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2018 Update 3.

The email alerts generated by TFS are very useful, but we have our Application server housed in the UK, while the whole team is in a different timezone Europe.

Is it possible to tell TFS to use the Europe timezone as the standard timezone, or would it always use the local system time on the application server ?

The Email alerts do show what time zone is used, but would be useful if they just show the local time for the users.

> Notes:
>   - All dates and times are shown in UTC+01:00:00 GMT Daylight Time